# Ignore JSF action method's return value

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el, jsf-2.2

I have a simple JSF form that almost doesn't need any Java code, it's just this:

```
<p:inputText required="true" value="#{newThing1}" />
<p:inputText required="true" value="#{newThing2}" />
<p:commandButton value="Add" action="#{bean.map.put(newThing1, newThing2)}" />
```

The map is some `java.util.Map` implementation. This almost works, with one problem: the `Map#put` returns the previous value associated with given key - and JSF tries to interpret this value as an outcome. Is there any way to circumvent this, so JSF would ignore this value? I guess I could create an EL function for the sole purpose of swallowing this value. But is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `actionListener` instead of `action`.